# RStudio does not read non-English characters in paths

Tags: r, rstudio

I want to list files and folders containing Japanese characters in my working directory with `list.files()`, but when I tried this, it does not show the proper files names.

For example, the "test" direcotry has folders "test1", "test2", "テスト3", and running `list.files()` gives unreadable characters for the one with Japanese characters like this.

```
> getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/10040153/Documents/test"
> list.files()
[1] "繝<86>繧ｹ繝<88>3" "test1" "test2"
```

#### What I tried

- Set "Default text encoding" to UTR-8
- Changed locale setting to Japanese with `sys.setlocale(locale = "Japanese")`, which returned `[1]"LC_COLLATE=Japanese_Japan.932;LC_CTYPE=Japanese_Japan.932;LC_MONETARY=Japanese_Japan.932;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Japanese_Japan.932"`
- Reinstalled R and RStudio
- Rebooted the computer

None of these didn' help.

I doubt this is an issue with RStudio, not R program, because I see no problems with running the same code above in R. Does anybody have an idea?

#### System environment

- Windows 10 x64
- RStudio
- R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)

#### Update

`` `Encoding<-`(list.files(), "UTF-8") `` solved the problem.

```
> `Encoding<-`(list.files(), "UTF-8")
[1] "テスト3" "test1"   "test2"
```

I know this has something do with encoding, but how can I make it work in global environemt?

Comment: What does `Sys.getlocale()` return ?

Comment: What's the result of `\`Encoding<-\`(list.files(), "UTF-8")`?

Comment: @cuttlefish44
`Sys.getlocale()` returns this:
[1]"LC_COLLATE=Japanese_Japan.932;LC_CTYPE=Japanese_Japan.932;LC_MONETARY=Japanese_Japan.932;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Japanese_Japan.932"

Comment: @RitchieSacramento, ``Encoding<-`(list.files(), "UTF-8"`) gives like this:

[1] "テスト3" "test1"   "test2"  

It seemed to go well, but how I make this work in global environment?

Comment: Try putting `LC_ALL=ja_JP.UTF-8` or just `LC_CTYPE=ja_JP.UTF-8` in `~/.Renviron`. (You may have to create the file.) Then restart R and retry `list.files()`.

Comment: @MikaelJagan, I tried with `LC_ALL=ja_JP.UTF-8` and yet got the same problem with the warning message when I startup the program.
`During startup - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_COLLATE=ja_JP.UTF-8 failed 
2: Setting LC_CTYPE=ja_JP.UTF-8 failed 
3: Setting LC_MONETARY=ja_JP.UTF-8 failed 
4: Setting LC_TIME=ja_JP.UTF-8 failed'

Comment: Sorry, Microsoft makes it difficult to find the correct locale names for Windows. Try `LC_CTYPE=Japanese_Japan.UTF-8` instead. I'm looking at [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/locale-names-languages-and-country-region-strings?view=msvc-170) in the Microsoft documentation as a reference.

Comment: @MikaelJagan, Thank you for your help. Unfortunatly, replacing underscore with hyphen did not work as well. Still get the same warning message and the situation doesn't change... `Sys.getlocale()` gives `LC_CTYPE=C` instead of `LC_CTYPE=Japanese_Japan.932` though.

Comment: @TKH_9 - It doesn't help today but note that the forthcoming R 4.2.0 release will provide native support for UTF-8 on Windows 10 - see https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2021/12/07/upcoming-changes-in-r-4.2-on-windows/

Comment: @RitchieSacramento Perfect timing as Windows users are switching to W11 ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in RStudio; see https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/10451. If you're willing to try a fix, we have one in the dailies as of last week:

https://dailies.rstudio.com/